# Click action with two functions: to add/remove class and toggle attribute value

Tags: javascript

I am working on a list of anchor links with nested anchor links and want to do a couple of things.

When clicking on a link:

1. add class of "current"
2. remove class of "current" from any other link or nested link
3. if the item has children, toggle the value of a data-attribute (i.e. data-children="visible" or data-children="hidden")
4. and the anchor link should still work

Just as a note, it does not matter to me whether or not the "data-children" attribute is on the parent a.link or on the div.children.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#l1" class="link">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#l2" class="link" data-children="hidden">Level 2</a>
        <div class="children">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#l2-1" class="link">Level 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#l2-2" class="link" data-children="hidden">Level 2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#l2-3" class="link">Level 2.3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#l3" class="link">Level 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
let el = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].onclick = function() {
    let c = 0;
    while (c < el.length) {
      el[c++].className = 'link';
    }
    el[i].className = 'link current';

    let x = el.getAttribute('data-children');
    if (x === 'visible') {
      el.setAttribute('data-children', 'visible');
    } else {
      el.setAttribute('data-children', 'hidden');
    }
  };
}
```

The expected result is to allow for any link to be the "current" link and the ability to toggle the display to any or all child links.

Clicking on a parent link will add the class="link current" and toggle attribute to data-children="visible". Clicking the parent link again will toggle the attribute to data-children="hidden" and the link will still have the class="link current"

Comment: are you using jquery ?

Comment: Each of those steps is easy to research. It's expected that you show some effort to solve your own issues before asking. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective is for you to show your attempts and people help you out when you are stuck with real code

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl for the feedback. I will update my example with the JS code that I have.

Comment: @charlietfl, I have added my JS code. I am able to set the "current" class but having trouble with toggling the attribute values.

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé, No, I am not using jquery but thank you for your example.

Comment: okok, i updated my answer

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé, Thanks! Your solution worked like a charm! Looking at it now, I don't know why I couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let el = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
    for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        el[i].onclick = function() {
            let c = 0;
            while (c < el.length) {
            el[c++].className = 'link';
            }
            el[i].className = 'link current';
            
            // toggle data-children attribute for clicked link and childs
            var hidden_node = el[i].parentNode.querySelectorAll('[data-children=hidden]');
            var visible_node = el[i].parentNode.querySelectorAll('[data-children=visible]');

            for (let i = 0; i < hidden_node.length; i++) {
                hidden_node[i].setAttribute('data-children', 'visible');
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < visible_node.length; i++) {
                visible_node[i].setAttribute('data-children', 'hidden');
            }
        };
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#l1" class="link">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#l2" class="link" data-children="hidden">Level 2</a>
        <div class="children">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#l2-1" class="link">Level 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#l2-2" class="link" data-children="hidden">Level 2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#l2-3" class="link">Level 2.3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#l3" class="link">Level 3</a></li>
</ul>
```